# Не работает MouseListener

Tags: java, события, listener

Решил поиграться со слушателями, и первым выбрал MouseListener и пришлось добавить ActionListener:

```
public class engine implements MouseListener, ActionListener {
    private sheath parent;
    engine(sheath parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        Object src = e.getSource();
        if(src == parent.btn) {
            parent.btn.setVisible(true);
            parent.btn.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        Object src = e.getSource();
        if(src == parent.btn) {
            parent.btn.setVisible(false);
            parent.btn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object src = e.getSource();
        if(src == parent.btn) {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Wow!", "Wow!",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно, чтобы когда курсор входил в кнопку, она активировалась и была видимой. Когда курсор выходит - все наоборот. Однако ничего не работает.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю происходящее, то условие не выполняется именно потому, что setVisible(false), и кнопка не возвращается в getSource(). Ее там какбы и нет. 
Можно попробовать ставить условие, сравнивая координаты мыши при ее движении с границами кнопки.

Comment: Ваш ответ меня устроил.

Answer (score 0):

Перенесу свой комментарий сюда.
Поправьте меня, если я не прав, но кнопка потому и не возвращается в getSource(), потому что она в setVisible(false). Ее как бы и нет.

Работающий вариант - это проверка координат мыши при ее движении на совпадение с областью кнопки.

```
if (mouseX <= btn.X+btn.Width && mouseX >= btn.X
&& mouseY <= btn.Y+btn.Height && mouseX >= btn.Y)
```